# dimension resource cannot be found in Xamarin for Android

Tags: android, xamarin

In a drawable XML file, I want to use a dimension resource "background_radius".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient 
    android:type="radial"
    android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:endColor="#00000"
    android:gradientRadius="@dimen/background_radius"
/>
</shape>
```

The dimension resource is defined in Values\Dimens.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="background_radius">400dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

I got the following error when I build it. 
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'gradientRadius' with value '@dimen/background_radius').  ...\Resources\drawable\background.xml

But when I design it in VS, I can see the correct background radius. It seems VS just cannot build it.

What's wrong?

Thanks.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++

For some unknown reason, the project did not pick up the new dimens xml file. I re-created the files and rebuild it. Now the dimen can be found.

In addition, the radial gradient does not like the dimen value with dp. so I update the dimen resource to:
    `<item name="background_radius" format="float" type="dimen">400</item>`

Answer (score 4):

Give your dimension a dimension unit (dp, sp, etc.)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

> A dimension value defined in XML. A dimension is specified with a number followed by a unit of measure. For example: 10px, 2in, 5sp.

So, change it to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="background_radius">400dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

for example.

Comment: I just notice it and update my question before I see your comment. Anyway, I still got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar thing; created a Colors.xml file and everything was as it should be but the resource could not be found. After a while I forgot about it and found that it had finally been picked up. Today made a Dimens.xml and the exact same thing happened.

I had to restart Visual Studio in order for it to be picked up.